# Can't try/catch error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using contoso university wb app. But I can't catch the error.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Student student)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    studentService.Add(student);
                    studentService.Update(student);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (DataException /* dex */)
            {
                //Log the error (uncomment dex variable name and add a line here to write a log.
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }
            return View(student);
        }
```

This is the image of the error:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2sw5gor3x2d1lpi/111111.jpg?dl=0

Comment: What do you mean you _cant catch the error_. You have caught the error and in the `catch` block you have added the message and returned the view to display it!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are catching the error!
That's why your error message `"Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator."` gets gracefully displayed in the browser and no runtime error saying that an exception occured.